# Storing an object in mysqli database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am developing a facebook app which requires me to store certain information in a mysqli database and then retrieve it.

Data is for example  `Array(1) { ["id"]=> string(17) "10213388667928851" }`

Please share your views as soon as possible.

Comment: This needs more work.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into string as serialized array ([serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)) or JSON document ([json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

The best solution depends on the project details.